# PHP codeigniter application on openshift showing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, openshift

I have created an application on openshift with PHP codeigniter. Added, committed, and pushed successfully using git, but when I click to view the application it shows:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

here is my link to application

http://stw-ciapps.rhcloud.com/

home page is working, but other pages not opening.

http://stw-ciapps.rhcloud.com/home/provider

How can I view my application and get rid of this 500 error.

Comment: please submit your code instead of link

Comment: Which part of code, as it is very large

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code with your old .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase / #on server, uncomment this line by removing hash'#'
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi, no error but no other page is not opening, only home page opening

Comment: Where is your codeigniter folder in /Home/ directory or in root directory.